# Using potentiometer to light three different LEDs (Multisim)

Tags: digital-logic, potentiometer, multisim

I want to make a circuit that connects a potentiometer to three different LEDs (green, blue, red.) This circuit would simulate the wind speed sensor.  If the potentiometer is high (V is high, therefore represents strong wind,) the red LED will light up. If the potentiometer is low (V low, meaning slow wind,) the green LED will light up. The blue LED will represent a medium speed wind.

Do I have to use comparators or logic gates in order to make sure the correct LED lights up? Does this mean that the threshold voltage for each LED is being set?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use something like the LM3914 bar graph driver chip. It has all the comparators and logic built in to give up to ten steps on your indicator in bar mode or dot mode.

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source [Nuts and Volts](https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/led-graph-circuits).*

The linked article explains it all.

If you really want to create one with discrete comparators then you can copy parts of the internal layout of the LM3914.

Comment: In terms of the OP's desire to light only 3 LEDs, would you simply for example connect the cathode of the Green LED in common to pins 1, 8, 17, and 16 etc?

Comment: If they're common-emitter outputs - it's a long time since I used the chip - then you could use pin 1, 18, and connect all the others to the third LED so that the last LED would remain on. Without that you'd get green, blue red, off ... If you connect the higher outputs you'd get green, blue, red, red, red ...